# Extracting the Most Current Year from my Dataset?

Tags: r

I am trying to partition my dataset into 2 separate datasets (`data` & `data2`). `'Data'` contains the data from this current year (2021), whereas `'Data2'` contains data from previous years.

Currently I have this chunk of code that separates the current year's data from the previous year's data :

```
data <- discrete_8 %>%  filter(PS_DATE >= as.POSIXct(paste0(substr(Sys.Date(),1,4),"-01-01")))#current year; filtered
data2 <- discrete_8 %>%  filter(PS_DATE < as.POSIXct(paste0(substr(Sys.Date(),1,4),"-01-01")) & PS_DATE > as.POSIXct("2013-12-31"))#previous year; filtered; remove year 2013


> as.POSIXct(paste0(substr(Sys.Date(),1,4),"-01-01"))
[1] "2021-01-01 UTC"
```

This is exactly what I want, except when the year 2022 comes, I am afraid that the data for the year 2022 will not be available, so this will create an error. I was thinking of extracting the most current year from my dataset, which would be the very last row in the dataset.

```
> tail(discrete_8)
     PS_NAME Offline.Cell.Days Offline.CSPR..perfusion.    PS_DATE
6275 x1                34                0.5856000 2021-06-16
6288 x2                47                0.6412710 2021-06-29
6289 x3                48                0.5066250 2021-06-30
6303 x4                47                0.7241379 2021-06-29
6304 x5                48                0.5206612 2021-06-30
6305 x6                49                0.5358987 2021-07-01
```

Is there a way where I can change my chunk of code so that, instead of using `Sys.Date()` to extract the most current year (currently not fail proof), I actually extract the most current year available in the dataset.

In one of my datasets, there are data only up until the year 2020, so my chunk of code does not work in that script. Extracting the year from the last row of data would work better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a year column to the dataset and extract the max year to get data for latest year.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

discrete_8 <- discrete_8 %>% mutate(year = year(as.Date(PS_DATE)))
data <- discrete_8 %>%  filter(year == max(year))
data2 <- discrete_8 %>%  filter(year != max(year))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
discrete_8_lst <- discrete_8 %>%
                 mutate(year = as.numeric(format(as.Date(PS_DATE), '%Y'))) %>%
                 group_split(grp = year == max(year))
```